# Reformatting text in Python

Tags: python, count, transpose

I am new to python and having great difficulty parsing through a log file.  Can you please help me understand how I can accomplish the below in the most Pythonic way.

```
----- Log Entry 5 -----
Time       : 2016-07-12 09:00:00
Animal     : Brown Bear
Bird       : White Owl
Fish       : Salmon


----- Log Entry 6 -----
Time       : 2016-07-12 09:00:00
Animal     : Brown Bear
Bird       : Parrot
Fish       : Tuna


----- Log Entry 7 -----
Time       : 2016-07-12 09:00:00
Animal     : Lion
Bird       : White Owl
Fish       : Sword Fish


----- Log Entry 8 -----
Time       : 2016-07-12 09:15:00
Animal     : Lion
Bird       : White Owl
Fish       : Sword Fish
```

Desired Output 1: I would like to reformat the log to look like the below:

```
Time: 2016-07-12 09:00:00 Animal: Brown Bear  Bird: White Owl  Fish : Salmon
Time: 2016-07-12 09:00:00 Animal: Brown Bear  Bird: Parrot     Fish : Tuna
Time: 2016-07-12 09:00:00 Animal: Lion        Bird: White Owl  Fish : Sword Fish
Time: 2016-07-12 09:15:00 Animal: Lion        Bird: White Owl  Fish : Sword Fish
```

Desired Output 2: Then I would like to have the ability to query a time stamp and get a summary of counts:

```
Time: 2016-07-12 09:00:00
Name:       Count:
Brown Bear  2
Lion        1
White Owl   2
Parrot      1
Salmon      1
Tuna        1
Sword Fish  1

Time: 2016-07-12 09:15:00
Name:       Count:
Lion        1
White Owl   1
Sword Fish  1
```

My Code So Far:

```
import os, sys, time, re, collections, subprocess

show_cmd = 'cat question |  egrep -v \'^$|=|Log\' | awk \'ORS=NR%4?FS:RS\' | grep Time'
log = (subprocess.check_output(show_cmd, shell=True).decode('utf-8'))

def time_field():
    logRegex = re.compile(r'Time\s*:.*\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d')
    log_parsed = (logRegex.findall(log))
    a = (str(log_parsed).replace('  ', ''))
    a = ((' ' + a[1:-1]).split(','))
    for i in a:
        print(i)

time_field()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulties are you facing in your current implementation? Can you please provide a [mcve] of your latest code attempt?

Comment: Have you been able to read the file in some way?

Comment: is what you're showing the expected output or is that supposed to be mirrored in dataformat?

Comment: what format is the data in? CSV, dataframe, dictionary, etc?

Comment: I have edited to show what I have been able to extract so far. However, when I try extract the second field I cant get them next to each other.

Comment: Have you looked at parsing this by just crawling through the log line by line and building it into a dict, then loading it into Pandas?  I ask because Pandas would make your 2nd goal trivial - along with many other types of analysis - but wouldn't exactly match your 1st goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Personally I would avoid using regex for this because it probably won't be more efficient and the expression becomes cumbersome and inflexible. Here is something I came up with:

```
class Entry:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = None
        self.animal = None
        self.bird = None
        self.fish = None

    def __repr__(self):
        fmt = "{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(
            "Time: {time: <{width}}",
            "Animal: {animal: <{width}}",
            "Bird: {bird: <{width}}",
            "Fish: {fish: <{width}}")
        return fmt.format(
            time=self.time, animal=self.animal,
            bird=self.bird, fish=self.fish,
            width=12)

    def __radd__(self, other):
            return self.__add__(other)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if type(other) == dict:
            for i in [self.animal, self.bird, self.fish]:
                if i in other: other[i] += 1
                else: other[i] = 1
            return other
        elif type(other) == Entry:
            return self.__add__({}) + other
        else:
            return self.__add__({})

def parse_log(path):
    def extract(line):
        start = line.find(':') + 1
        return line[start:].strip()

    entries = []
    entry = None
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.startswith('-----'):
                if entry: entries.append(entry)
                entry = Entry()
            elif line.startswith('Time'):
                entry.time = extract(line)
            elif line.startswith('Animal'):
                entry.animal = extract(line)
            elif line.startswith('Bird'):
                entry.bird = extract(line)
            elif line.startswith('Fish'):
                entry.fish = extract(line)

        if entry: entries.append(entry)

    return entries


def print_output_1(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        print entry

def print_output_2(entries, time):
    animals = sum([e for e in entries if e.time == time])

    print "Time: {0}".format(time)
    print "Name:        Count:"
    for animal, count in animals.items():
        print "{animal: <{width}} {count}".format(
                animal=animal, count=count, width=12)


logPath = 'log.log'
time = '2016-07-12 09:15:00'
entries = parse_log(logPath)

print_output_1(entries)
print ""
print_output_2(entries, time)
```

The output (given that `log.log` matches the input you gave) is:

```
Time: 2016-07-12 09:00:00 Animal: Brown Bear   Bird: White Owl    Fish: Salmon
Time: 2016-07-12 09:00:00 Animal: Brown Bear   Bird: Parrot       Fish: Tuna
Time: 2016-07-12 09:00:00 Animal: Lion         Bird: White Owl    Fish: Sword Fish
Time: 2016-07-12 09:15:00 Animal: Lion         Bird: White Owl    Fish: Sword Fish

Time: 2016-07-12 09:15:00
Name:        Count:
White Owl    1
Sword Fish   1
Lion         1
```

The way this code works is to use object oriented programming to our advantage in order to simplify the tasks we need to do: store log entries, represent log entries in a specific format, and combine log entries according to a specific property.

First, note that the `Entry` object and its properties (`self.time`, `self.animal`, `self.bird`, `self.fish`) represents an entry in the log. Assuming that the information stored in its properties is correct, a method can be created to represent that information as a formatted string. The method `__repr__()` is called when python wants the string representation of an object, so it seemed like a good place to put this code. There is heavy use of the `format` function in this method, but it should be clear how it works after browsing the python documentation on `format`.

A method for combining these entry objects is needed in order to get the second output you specified. This can be done many ways and the way I did it is not necessarily the best. I used the `__radd__()` and `__add__()` methods which are called when the `+` operator is used on an object. By doing this, the code `entry1 + entry2` or `sum([entry1, entry2])` can be used to get the sum of the animals in both entries. The `Entry` class can not be used to store the result of the sum, however, because it cannot contain arbitrary information. Instead, I chose to use a `dict` object to be the result of summing two `Entry` objects. In order to sum more than two `Entry` objects, `Entry` must also be able to sum with a `dict` object because `Entry + Entry + Entry` results in `dict + Entry`.

The `__add__()` function checks if the object it is being added to is a `dict` object. If this is the case, it checks if each of the animals in the entry exist in the `dict` already. If not, it will add the animal as a key. Otherwise, it will increment the value of that key. `__radd__()` is similar to `__add__()` except that it is used in some special circumstances. See the python documentation for more information.

For the case where the object is an `Entry`, code could have been written to gather all of the animals from each `Entry` object and create a `dict` from that information, but since there is already code to add an `Entry` with a `dict` it is easier to first add one object to an empty `dict` and then add the resulting `dict` with the other `Entry` object.

For all other objects, the `Entry` will simply return the `dict` description of itself, or itself added with an empty `dict`.

Now all of the tools exist to accomplish the goals listed earlier. To get a string representation of an `Entry` that matches desired output 1, all that is needed is `print entry` or `strrepr = str(entry)`. To get desired output 2, a little more work is involved, but it is simply summing all entries that have the same `self.time` property and then displaying the resulting dict.

The last part of the code not covered is the parsing of the log to create a list of `Entry` objects. The code simply walks line by line through the log and populates an `Entry` with the information. I feel like this is pretty straightforward, but you can feel free to ask questions if it does not make sense.

Comment: This accomplished exactly what I was looking for! To be honest I need to spend some serious time to try and understand your method. I am a newbie at Python but this is a great reference for me since I deal with a lot of logs in this format. Thank you very much for your prompt reply and support!

Comment: I added an explanation of the code that hopefully makes it more clear. If this answer meets your needs feel free to mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks Alden for the explanation. That was very helpful!